# Issue with download speed with DownloadOperation

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient

I have an UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application on Windows Store and this application is nothing but an audio/video downloader on internet with my `DownloadOperation` class.

`DownloadOperation` speed is very slow regardless of internet speed.

When the audio/video size is less than average of 5MB then the speed of downloading is very slow compared to file size greater then 30-40 MB. But the overall speed of my downloading is in Kilobytes per second.

I notice this download speed from task manager application sometimes and sometimes using my network tools. Tried using `HttpClient` instead of `DownloadOperation` but that doesn't produce any difference in my case.

Example Code :

```
        string source =
            @"https://r1---sn-nv47lnes.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-AF3ULlrgm4d4p8IDGAzJbL8LUsQ7xOkiD5zYJAiTJGTT&mv=m&mt=1531996353&ms=au,onr&mn=sn-nv47lnes,sn-4g5ednly&mm=31,26&ip=213.14.6.130&pl=22&itag=17&gir=yes&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=493750&source=youtube&ei=K2lQW4uRNYyRgAOi7rPYDA&lmt=1385600724132940&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&ipbits=0&fexp=23709359,23745105&fvip=1&clen=2754619&dur=268.329&c=WEB&key=yt6&mime=video/3gpp&expire=1532018060&signature=9DB761B443EAB96C65E69BAF1A3923D9E64093C4.4AAF9E5E8CA43E0426D59ECFFF9D84638AA8DD81&ratebypass=yes";
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("omansak.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        BackgroundDownloader backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        DownloadOperation downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(source), file);
        await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(new Progress<DownloadOperation>(operation =>
        {
            BackgroundDownloadProgress currentProgress = downloadOperation.Progress;
            if (currentProgress.TotalBytesToReceive > 0)
            {
                var percent = (int)(currentProgress.BytesReceived * 100 / currentProgress.TotalBytesToReceive);
                button1.Content = percent.ToString() + "-" + currentProgress.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString();
            }

        }));
```

For example , this download code take 40 sec wirh DownloadOperation but normally avg 3sec . 
How to use maximum network (i.e., maximum speed of internet) while downloading file?

Comment: There are many variables in this equation not the least of which is the max downlink speed of the remote host serving the files. You'll need to provide a lot more detail about the systems involved to get a useful answer here.

Comment: Application downloads audio/video on Youtube. You can try application. "PlayList Downloader on YouTube" on Windows 10 Store

Comment: I have tested your app it does not work in my side. You need add some key points such as code simple sample, otherwise, we hardly to give an answer based on incomplete information.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT my code like this https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer/cs/BackgroundTransfer/Scenario7_DownloadReordering.xaml.cs

Comment: I have tested with official code sample but i could not reproduce your issue, and it download with full speed in my side. Have you tested with another downloader?

Comment: @PeterM.Elias edited thread :

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT edited thread

Comment: Ok, I will check.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT
i found a solution via: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/8a0ef89a-0b68-4c64-8fdd-0b345fde239c/uwpvb-more-frequent-updates-of-progressof-downloadoperation?forum=wpdevelop

but this solution so bad

Comment: Your mean download speed is normal, progress update is slow, am right?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT no both of this are is slow